# Recent replies icon lights up even when there are no replies

Tags: bug, status-completed

I sometimes have the envelope icon next to my name on the top row lighted up (rendered filled in yellow) even when clicking on it shows no recent replies. Is this a known bug?

Comment: I've seen it light up even when a comment addressed to you gets deleted. How do I know this? I saw the comment from the popup box from clicking the upper left "StackExchange" dropdown. (It eventually disappeared, though.)

Comment: Did you check your favourites?

Comment: @Moron. No. But I was expecting that if the envelope lights up then clicking on it should show something. Sometimes it shows nothing. That I think is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "psychic envelope" has been a known issue for a long time, but it was recently said to be fixed. If you find the problem reappearing, please report to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61012/any-progress-with-the-envelope-indicator.

The envelope will light up when your favorite is updated too.

(This is a back-end issue, please report to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ in the future.)